# choosing a random image from a string that located in array with for loop

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, arrays, xcode

I want to write something, but I don't have any idea how to do it and where to start with it.

So, I have an array called `imagesArray` that contains 20 images of animals for example, lets say that the 5 first images of the array will be a images of : Rabbit.png, Horse.png, Lizard.png, Mouse.png and Dog.png.

So in the array that called `wordsArray` I will have in items in index range 0-4: "Rabbit", "Horse", "Lizard", "Mouse" and "Dog" and so on...

Also I have 4 `UIButtons`.

What I want the program to is, when the for loop is on `item0`, meaning that `i=0`, the image from `imagesArray` is Rabbit.png and the word from wordsArray is "Rabbit", I want to choose a random letter from the word "Rabbit" and display it once on one of the 4 `UIButton`s, the other 3 `UIButton`s will display any other letters but different letters.

I still didn't find a good way to do it. maybe its because I'm kinda new to Objective-C or programming at all..

How can I manage to do that?

**EDIT**

I have this code, but its not good because its working with UIImages instead of words and I dont know how to do it with words..

```
-(void)placeWordAndPictueOnScreen
{
    // sets the letter in a random button
    NSMutableArray * ButtonArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:btnLetter1,btnLetter2,btnLetter3,btnLetter4, nil];
    int CorrectImg = random() % [ButtonArray count];
    imgclick = CorrectImg;
    UIImage * img = [UIImage imageNamed:[LettersArray objectAtIndex:imgcounter]];

    UIButton * btn = [ButtonArray objectAtIndex:CorrectImg];
    [btn setImage:img forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [ButtonArray removeObjectAtIndex:CorrectImg];

    // sets the other buttons with random letters
    while ([ButtonArray count] != 0)// how many times u want to run this
    {
        int imgRand = random() % [LettersArray count]; //number for random image
        int btnRand = random() % [ButtonArray count]; //number for random button
        //get that random image
        UIImage * img = [UIImage imageNamed:[LettersArray objectAtIndex:imgRand]];
        //get that random button
        UIButton * button = [ButtonArray objectAtIndex:btnRand];
        //put image on that button
        [button setImage:img forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [ButtonArray removeObjectAtIndex:btnRand];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that the next method will help you

```
    -(NSMutableArray *)getStringInArray:(NSString *)string{
    NSMutableArray *charsArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    while (![string isEqualToString:@""]) {
        [charsArray addObject:[string substringToIndex:1]];
        string=[string substringFromIndex:1];
    }
    return [charsArray autorelease];
}
```

Comment: actually it dosent what I ment to do.. tell me please, how can I take a string for example "hello", I want to split this string into an array, item 0: 'h' item1: 'e' item2: 'l' item3: 'l' item 4: 'o'. how can i do that?